# Чи є слово "пилосос" нормативним в українській мові?

Tags: росіянізм, іменники

Найчастіше зустрічаю саме це слово на позначення відомого пристрою в розмовному спілкуванні та, наприклад, в магазинах побутової техніки. Чи правильне воно?

Багато користувачів інтернету пропонують такі варіанти: *порохотяг*, *пилосмок*, *пилотяг* і т.ін. Проте як утворити від перелічених іменників дієслова, що позначатимуть процес прибирання цим пристроєм (за аналогією до "*пилососити*")?

Comment: " порохотяжити"

Comment: В радянських повоєнних словниках було лише «пилосос».

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Слово «пилосос» однозначно є:

1. Його фіксує академічний «Словник української мови» в 11 томах (том 6, 1975): [пилосос](http://sum.in.ua/s/pylosos).
2. Його фіксує «Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» В. Бесела (2005): [пилосос](http://www.lingvo.ua/uk/Interpret/uk-ru/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81).
3. Його фіксує електронний словник Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України (2008): [пошук в ULIF](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/).
4. Його фіксує «Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки)» О. Кочерги та Є. Мейнаровича (2010р.): [пилосос](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81&dicts=4,5) — хоча й з помітками *заст[аріле]* в одному місці та *н[е]р[е]к[омендоване]* в іншому.
5. Його неодноразово вживають в художній прозі 1971–2014 років: [пошук у корпусі](http://www.mova.info/corpus.aspx) (а також підручниках і публіцистиці).
6. Його наводить як один з припустимих варіантів професор О. Пономарів:

   > Запитання: Який найкращий відповідник російського речення: «Пропылесось свою комнату»? 
   >   Відповідь: Для приладу, що вбирає пил, в українській мові є кілька назв: пилосос, пилосмок, пилотяг. В українському перекладі наведене речення має такий вигляд: «Прибери в своїй кімнаті пилососом (пилосмоком, пилотягом).»

   — [звідси](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/10/151006_ponomariv_blog69_ko) (2015).

Звісно, можна довго дискутувати щодо оптимальності цього слова. Хтось вважає його найбільш усталеним варіантом, а хтось — пережитком радянської доби. Пуристи ніколи не погодяться з не пуристами (хоча О. Пономарів в деяких випадках виявляє себе радше як пурист). Серед інших варіантів, яким багато хто надає перевагу перед «пилососом»:

- пилосмо́к<sup>2, 4, 5, 6</sup>, пилотя́г<sup>5 (рідко), 6</sup>; порохотя́г<sup>4, 5 (рідко)</sup>, порохозбира́ч<sup>4</sup>, знепоро́шувач<sup>4</sup> (значення цифр — див. вище; «пилотяг» і «порохотяг» зустрічаються в корпусі лише одноразово; «пилосмок» має давню історію з 1924–1930, з'являючись в «Російсько-українському академічному словнику» А. Кримського та С. Єфремова, «Російсько-українському словнику технічної термінології» І. Шелудька та Т. Садовського та «Російсько-українському словнику» О. Ізюмова — [див.](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA&dicts=1,2,4)).

Щодо аналогів слова «пилососити», то існування самого слова «пилососити» викликає сумніви:

- О. Пономарів, як зазначено вище, як відповідник російського «пылесосить» пропонував застосовувати «прибирати пилососом».
- В українському лінгвістичному корпусі лабораторії комп'ютерної лінгвістики Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка «пилососити» зустрічається достатньо рідко (5 разів в художній прозі та 2 в науковій літературі).
- В словниках, наскільки я знаю, «пилососити» не зустрічається (окрім так званих «народних», «відкритих» тощо, що не мають академічної значимості).

Мені саме «пилососити» виглядає грубою калькою російського «пылесосить».